# IIS on Domain Server, Cannot Access To Website from Remote

Tags: active-directory, remote-access, iis-8.5

I recently rent a virtual server over some country, and activate it's ISS service and Active Directory....

What now bother me, though i had no idea what i'm doing (though most of it went right) is that, i had a project (MVC 5, Dot Net 4.5),... so i add a Website to Sites node(name it ChatSystem), and then add Application to it, named it "chat"

when i locally access the page, even using server IP, i can access the page, but when i do it remotely it gave me timeout error, do some research, i did many thing...
Define new service user ( named it "IISService"), and tell application pool to use that user, gave explicit windows access to "ChatSystem" User and "IISService" User for access the folders of "ChatSystem" and "Chat" Application, increase Session timeout to 3600, and several more thing i dont remember, now i'm wonder what else i can do, that i can access it from else where...

And let say it's my first time using IIS since windows XP, and it's also first time i use Active Directory (need it for something, without having any idea what it do, at last i understand what it do, but i still have many trouble since biult-in users became un-usable)

Thank you,
Hassan F.

PS: Ain't IIS and Firewall fault this forum issues? :| i don't see super  user fit my question any better...

Comment: With "locally" do you mean from the server itself or from the same LAN segment?

Comment: i use remote desktop to reach server, and i login with administrator user... so there, i have a chrom browser installed on server, there i type: `[machin name|localhost|127.0.0.1|serverIP]:port/chat` and i can open the web page

Comment: Do you have an public IP address to access your Server? If your service provider does not filter web traffic, you should simply be able to access your site using _http://<public IP address>_. I am assuming you meant to say that you activated **IIS** service and not ISS.

Comment: isn't iis service activated by default?
i can reach web page created by other app...
yes i have IP address

Comment: :| gain minus rate because some one cant answer me :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After showing IIS to one of my partner, he guide me to binding, and change application port, with other one, once it worked, i though `may it be the firewall` ... searching over net, and confige firewall for the port, and every thing run smoothy... :) Inbound Role -> Add New Role -> Choose Port -> Set Port -> and Allow, and ok